# Opening Other Email Accounts using MailKit

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I'm trying to access to an IMAP account (Not My Default) using MailKit (created by jstedfast)

I can access my exchange email account using Imap fine and loop through the folders.

What I really need to do is access other email accounts I have rights to so I can monitor them for unread email that matches a certain query

I cannot figure out how to open a different mailbox then my own using my credentials.

In outlook I just add the additional mailboxes

How would be the best way to do it without using the other email account user?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't limited to a single ImapClient instance, so you can just create multiple ImapClient objects to connect to multiple accounts (1 account per ImapClient).